# Console.log output vs return output not the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, return

Ive never experienced this and maybe someone could explain to me whats happening?

```
const columns = Object.values(props[1]).map((x, i) =>{
            console.log(x) <- output: {name: "companyName", label: "Company", dataType: "string", width: 200, tooltip: "", …}
            return x
        })

console.log(columns) <- output: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Why are they outputting differently? I need it to look like the console.log(x) inside the map.
I assumed console.log(x) and console.log(columns) would be the same.

Comment: Map returns an array (of objects here). While you're in the map loop, they are just individual objects.

Comment: `map` returns an array of mapped values where `x` here is each individual value in the array. They will obviously be different

Comment: Ahh, Yes that makes sense. Geesh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are presumably mapping 4 values in props[1] to be {name:....} and assigning it to columns thus getting [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]

of-course, columns is `not` same as x but [ x, x, x, x]

Comment: Yes! Thanks, Totally make sense. Brainfart!